# Small charge on capacitor

Tags: charge

If I attempt to charge a 1 pF capacitor from an ideal 1 uV voltage source, what voltage would I measure across the capacitor?

Comment: Why not 1 micro farad capacitor and say 10V, that would be much more realistic. Anyway, you would measure the voltage applied, what else do you think?

Comment: You would measure the voltage to which the capacitor has been charged to.

Comment: Before you reply, calculate the charge on the capacitor and relate it to the charge of the electron

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg if you know the answer, don't ask or provide the answer yourself. Your comment makes me want to delete my answer.

Comment: Is this a trick question, like *"how long is one inch?*".

Comment: @OlinLathrop - since the USA adopted the metric system, one inch is 25.4mm ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you charge a capacitor to 1uV, then measure the voltage, you would see 1uV, assuming an ideal measurement.

There are lots of ways to make a non-ideal measurement, which would result in other readings.

Amongst the issues of whether a measurement is ideal or not would include things like what the noise level was on the 1uV charging voltage, whether the voltmeter draws any current from the capacitor, whether its input capacitance is pre-charged, and the noise level of the meter.

Answer (score 1):

Well with these properties, you are in the area of single electrons.

In an ideal world:

$$Q=C*U = 1 pF * 1 µV = 1*10^{-18} C$$

A single electron has a charge of 1.602e-19 C. So there would be 6.24 electrons on that capacitor, which is impossible. There would probably be 6 on that capacitor as the voltage is not enough to get a seventh on it.

With 6 electrons you get 9.61e-19 C. And using the formula above, you would measure: **0.961 µV.** (after disconnecting the voltage source from the capacitor)

In the real world this will be a daunting task, maybe some of the best institutions are able to pull off something like this as I read something about single electron counting somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that it needs 6.24 electrons as mentioned in another answer the voltage will still be 1uV.

How do you get 0.24 electrons?

In reality the electrons will be bouncing in and out, or more accurately, approaching and receding from the plate surface, and the odd one will even leak through.

However, on average there WILL be, effectively, 6.24 electrons on the plate.